# Robot Framework - how to get result from sh file execution

Tags: sh, robotframework

I use Robot Framework to execute *.sh script file:

```
${output}    Run Process   "../resources/scripts/TEST.sh"   shell=yes   alias=proc
Log    ${output}
```

${output} shows only <result object with rc 1>

I used also:

```
@{res}    Get Process Result  proc
```

Result: Cannot set variable '@{res}': Expected list-like value, got ExecutionResult.

So there is a problem with format.

If I execute the script in git bash I'll see smth like:

```
************************** PAGE HTML **************************
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 06 Mar 2024 15:44:32 GMT
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=node0124h4iezb4fdc16vay6u58f0en29.node0; Path=/; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=1140
```

etc

Could you help me to read an execution result, please?

Comment: Now the code looks like
`${command}    Set Variable    ${CURDIR}/TEST.sh>${CURDIR}/output.txt
Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Remove File    ${CURDIR}/output.txt 
${result}    Run Process   ${command}   shell=yes   alias=proc    stderr=${CURDIR}/STDERR.txt`

but the output file is still empty

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to redirect the output to a file.
This is the example from the library documentation, [here](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Run%20Process):

```
${result} = Run Process ${command}  stdout=${CURDIR}/stdout.txt stderr=STDOUT
```

Other possibily is for you to remove the option `shell=yes`.

Edit: You should try to use an absolute path for the command.

Comment: the file stdout.txt is still empty
I even added the part ">${CURDIR}/output.txt" to command
In git bash it works perfectly, but the file output.txt is still empty

Comment: WHen I remove "shell=yes" it just sents me "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]"
I ve changed the path many times and it doesnt find it